# properties of real differentiable function

Tags: derivatives

[problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TW8MV.jpg)

I have tried to investigate f according to given criteria but dont seem to go nowhere,

supposedly i have could show that according to given criteria f must be either strictly positive and growing or strictly negative and decreasing

but i do not know how to go further in proving the given statement

thanks in advance for your help

Comment: Please don't use pictures.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that $$
\left(f(x)e^{-cx}\right)'=f'(x)e^{-cx}-cf(x)e^{-cx}\geq 0.
$$
Which implies that
$$
f(x)\geq e^{cx} \frac{f(x_0)}{e^{cx_0}}=f(x_0) e^{c(x-x_0)} 
$$
for all $x> x_0$. Applying continuity at $a$ gives you the desired. You can prove the other inequality similarly.

Comment: was just getting to it after reading about Grönwall's inequality, thank you very much :) i think i can complete everything with this knowledge. would totally give you an up score or something if i knew how :)

Comment: Yeah. I just realised that Grönwall is sort of overkill for this question.